# Vue component not rendering & DevTools hanging

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I apologise by the confusing title but I am completely baffled by this and I think it has something to do with how Express serves static files but cannot be of that for sure.

I am creating a simple Vue app served by Express statically.

**server/app.js** *(entry point)*

```
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();

// Sends static files from the public path directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));

// Use morgan to log request in dev mode
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
}));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${process.env.PORT}`);
});

// Server index.html page when request to the root is made
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {
        root: path.join(__dirname, "..", "public"),
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**public/main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

import App from "./App";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: { App },
    template: "<App/>",
});
```

**public/App.vue**

```
<template>
    Hello World!
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "App",
    };
</script>

<style>
    #app {}
</style>
```

*App.vue* and *main.js* will only be loaded in if I uncomment that statically serving line.

This is just a simple UI page, nothing extravagant. In Chrome, I get a blank page with just the title "Hello World" on the tab. I am not able to open DevTools either and the Chrome extension I have does not recognise Vue as running on the page

In Mozilla, same result as Chrome but can see DevTools and it is just the basic HTML and there is no sign of other files *(even if I serve the files in `public`)* being loaded. There are also no errors in the logs here.

There are no errors in the server logs. I used to get a response in the logs when hitting the root endpoint but, for some reason, I no longer am.

I realise this is not a lot to go off but if anyone has any initial thoughts they would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT**

To clarify, when I serve files from `public` dir, I can hit them in the browser i.e. *http://localhost:3000/App.vue*

**EDIT 2**

I have added a basic `webpack.config` to bundle my Vue and JS files but I am getting the same behaviour.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: `${__dirname}/public/main.js`,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "client"),
        filename: "client.min.js",
    },
    target: "node",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            ".js",
            ".vue",
        ],
        modules: [
            "node_modules",
        ],
    },
    externals: [
        nodeExternals(),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        "es2015",
                    ],
                },  
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: true,
        }),
    ],
};
```

When looking at the DevTools in Firefox, the `<script>` to include `client.min.js` is present but there is still nothing displayed.

Comment: Assuming you're using a bundler like Webpack, have you built the Vue app? Is Express serving the built `index.html`?

Comment: change the template of **App.vue** to`<template>
   <div>Hello World!</div>
</template>` then try again.

Comment: @Sphinx I have done that and no change

Comment: @Phil I am not using any bundler at all. The idea was to build this up from barebones and then add in niceties like webpack

Comment: You need something to compile all your source and vendor files (ie bundle) and inject them into your `index.html` file. As you can see, your current `index.html` file has no `<script>` tags or much of anything else.

Comment: @Phil I have attempted to inject a `<script>` tag into my `index.html` but I get the same result

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. You can't just stick a `<script>` tag in your HTML file. You need something to compile / transpile your `.vue` files to JavaScript. Then you need something to bundle all the `import`-ed modules as browser's don't really support module loading (yet). You can't just _"add a bundler"_ later; it's a fundamental part of the way you structure and build your app

Comment: @Sphinx that's assuming OP has set up the project that way (ie from `vue-cli`) but I don't think they have

Comment: Ah yes thank you @Phil. I think that just bypassed me when implementing this. And no @Sphinx I have not setup the project that way. Phil, if you could come up with an answer then I would gladly accept. I sort of forgot how `.vue` works

Comment: As others have mentioned you *will* need a build process, if, you're not wanting to deal with that right now and just try vue without dealing with build tools (don't blame ya, haha) there's things like codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vue which allow you to play around with diff frameworks and do the building info for you. You can even export the project with the webpack config setup for you.

Comment: Thank you @subhaze ! I have heard of codesandbox @ a meetup I went to but yet to explore. I will have a look :)

Comment: Are there any errors in your console now? What about the _Network_ console? Any files not loading correctly?

Comment: There were no errors showing in the console at all. I have found another way around this and have ended up using vue-cli but served it with Express. I did this as it already has a predefined webpack config which is what I was struggling with. In any case, your answer has helped me understand Vue more and did help resolve my problem so I have accepted :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current project structure needs a bundler like Webpack. As mentioned in the comments, this is not something you can simply *"add later"*.

First, single-file `.vue` components must be *built*. Browser's don't know how to interpret the format. This task is usually done by a *loader* (see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader).

Second, browsers don't generally support module imports (this is changing though) so you need something to turn all those `import` statements into a bundle of scripts that can execute in your HTML page.

I highly recommend starting your project via the *vue-cli* tools. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli.

---

You can work with Vue by including it in your HTML page, ie

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

but this will fundamentally change how your source code is organised and you may find it impossible to make use of some 3rd party inclusions unless they too support general `<script>` tag use. You'll need to create components using the [`Vue.component()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) (or similar) syntax.

Comment: Hi Phil, can you please see my latest edit which I have added a webpack confíg. This is only bundling the client and not the server. I am still getting the same result and am not sure as to why. I have used vue-cli in the past but the reason I am not using it here is that I want to build it from the ground up with no boilerplate. I am also serving with Express in Dev/prod over webpack which vue-cli does not do as default